# Where and when do HTML tables add white space to the bottoms of cells or rows?

Tags: html, image, html-table, whitespace

When and where does HTML decide to add white space to its tables despite using cellpadding and cellspacing set to zero? I'm working on an HTML email and am unable to use CSS. Now I've stripped down the code just about as far as it can be stripped down to see where the error is hiding. Here's what I've got:

```
<body>                      
<table width="600" bgcolor="#000000" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
               <td align="left" valign="bottom" width="200"><img width="200" height="38" src="img/lineone.jpg"></td>
               <td align="left" bgcolor="#000000" valign="bottom"><img  src="img/linetwo.jpg" width="293"></td>
               <td align="left" valign="bottom" width="107"><img width="107" src="img/rewardslogo.jpg"></td>
      </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

When I look at this in the browser, it looks like this: (note the black line underneath the the bottom of the table. That shouldn't be there.)
[image: Black line running along the bottom of the table. It should be there and I need to get rid of it.]

Any ideas, suggestions, or explanations would be greatly appreciated. I guess I simply don't understand how HTML creates the table and why it seems to ignore the `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` attributes. The code was originally much more complicated with many more nested tables but this is about as simple as I can get the heading of the email to look and the problem still remains. Any ideas?

Here is a demo of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/mbc8r/

I changed the bgcolor of the cells so that you can see more clearly where each cell ends.

Comment: Did you inspect the rendered HTML in the browser to see what was causing it?

Comment: Yes and it's not the images. It's either the table or the cells themselves. It just lumps the extra spacing in with the `<table>`

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue in a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net), or maybe have a link to this test page?

Comment: The logo image on the right has the dimensions of 107 x 110. The cell it is in creates the dimensions 107 x 114. But adding a height doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Good idea. I edited the question with a JSFiddle link. Thanks! Let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should fix it:

```
table img {display:block;}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/wpMv5/)

Comment: This resolved the issue. I'm not really supposed to be using CSS on this project but I think `display:block;` will work in most browsers and web email clients. Thanks again! Much appreciated!

Comment: @user2662333 if it's for an email newsletter you can use inline styling - just add `style="display:block;"` to your image tags

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
<tr style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
```

Comment: thanks for your response! It didn't seem to help at first but `display:block;` did. Thanks again for your help!